# aumentar espaços entre 3 li's em inline-block CSS

Tags: html, css

{eu quero separa-las mais para que possa caber pequenas imagens, sem precisar diminuir a imagem muito][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP2rJ.jpg)

```
                <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="resultado.html">Resultado</a></li>

                <li><a href="contatos.html">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Usa CSS...
Coloca um nome de classe na ul, exemplo: , depois no seu CSS você coloca:
.header {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}